# Is there a name for a javascript function that returns a function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, nomenclature

Javascript allows us to write functions that use their parameters to build and return another (often anonymous) function with specific behaviour. [Currying](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/) is an example of this.

To illustrate, this approach can be used to elegantly sort an array of objects on an arbitrary property:

```
var sortOn = function(property) {
  return function(a,b) {
    return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]);
  };
};
var myArray = [ {id:1, title:'Hello'}, {id:2, title:'Aloha'} ];
myArray.sort( sortOn('title') ); // Aloha, Hello
myArray.sort( sortOn('id') );    // Hello, Aloha
```

Generally speaking, is there a word for a Javascript function that, based on its parameters, returns another function?

Answer (score 3):

A function that returns a function is called a higher order function.

It's a functional concept which is mainly used to abstract away parts of doing something into smaller bits, making it much quicker to code efficiently and cleanly.

Your function is a higher order function as it returns a function that creates a closure from its arguments - it's as simple as that.  A higher order function can also be one that returns something by a function which uses the result of another function given as an argument to make the result.

A functor is just a synonym for a function object - that is, you are able to pass a function as though it is any ordinary variable.  In JavaScript, all functions (whether declared, anonymous/named function expressions, or functions made using the function constructor or even built-in functions) can be passed as ordinary variables, therefore functions in JavaScript are first-class objects.  This does not really apply to your function though, as you are returning a function, not passing a function as an argument.

Comment: Be careful when using the term "functor": it has multiple, unrelated meanings in functional programming.

Comment: @MattFenwick: while true, I attempted to use it as given in the context given.

Answer (score 2):

In computer science generally, a function that operates on functions as input or output is called a "higher order function."